# How to animate width in this ajax poll from w3schools

Tags: php, jquery, css, ajax

*in this poll example on w3schools, the width appear immediately after i choose yes or no.what i want is to animate the width  . i've searched for another examples with animation but i still can't apply the animation in this example.

What is the best way to achieve this? *

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function getVote(int) {
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {  // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
      document.getElementById("poll").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","poll_vote.php?vote="+int,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body><div id="poll">
<h3>Do you like PHP and AJAX so far?</h3>
<form>
Yes:
<input type="radio" name="vote" value="0" onclick="getVote(this.value)">
<br>No:
<input type="radio" name="vote" value="1" onclick="getVote(this.value)">
</form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

```html
<?php
$vote = $_REQUEST['vote'];

//get content of textfile
$filename = "poll_result.txt";
$content = file($filename);

//put content in array
$array = explode("||", $content[0]);
$yes = $array[0];
$no = $array[1];

if ($vote == 0) {
  $yes = $yes + 1;
}
if ($vote == 1) {
  $no = $no + 1;
}
//insert votes to txt file
$insertvote = $yes."||".$no;
$fp = fopen($filename,"w");
fputs($fp,$insertvote);
fclose($fp);
?>

<h2>Result:</h2>
<table>
<tr>
<td>Yes:</td>
<td>
 <div style="background-color: blue; width:<?php echo(100*round($yes/($no+$yes),2)); ?>px; height:20px "> 
<?php echo(100*round($yes/($no+$yes),2)); ?>%
 </div>  
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>No:</td>
<td>
<div style="background-color: blue; width:<?php echo(100*round($no/($no+$yes),2)); ?>px; height:20px "> 
<?php echo(100*round($no/($no+$yes),2)); ?>%
 </div>  
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: 1st: you're missing the closing tag for div 'poll': `<div id="poll"></div>`

Comment: 2nd: `int` is a reserved word in js, so rename `int` to something like `value` or `vote`

Comment: 3rd: you're missing closing `;` in style-definition after height. That should not make an error, but still better learn to code precisely! - same after `<? php echo .....; ?>`

Comment: 4th: it's not a considered good programming style to mix data with templating. It would be better to receive data only from php and do the design/templating in your html.

Comment: I take back point 1, as the closing div is way back down, I did not see it... sorry. Also point 2 seems to work in their example with `int`

Comment: but here's the difference you've made to the (working) example: You've change the img to a background. Fair enough. But in the style-definition I think you need to add `px` to width.

Comment: thank you , i'll keep this in mind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I found a way using css animation property and here is the code in the edited php page*

```html
<?php
$vote = $_GET['vote'];

//get content of textfile
$filename = "poll_result.txt";
$content = file($filename);

//put content in array
$array = explode("||", $content[0]);
$yes = $array[0];
$no = $array[1];

if ($vote == 0) {
  $yes = $yes + 1;
}
if ($vote == 1) {
  $no = $no + 1;
}

//insert votes to txt file
$insertvote = $yes."||".$no;
$fp = fopen($filename,"w");
fputs($fp,$insertvote);
fclose($fp);
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
 <style type="text/css">
   .q1{
      width:  <?php echo intval(100*round($yes/($no+$yes),2));?>px;
      height: 20px;
      background-color: red; 
      animation-name: first;
      animation-duration: 1s;
      animation-delay: 0s;
      -webkit-animation-name: first;
      -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
      -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
    }

    @keyframes first {
      0% {width: 0px;}
      100% {width: <?php echo(100*round($yes/($no+$yes),2));?>;}
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes first {
      0% {width: 0px;}
      100% {width: <?php echo(100*round($yes/($no+$yes),2));?>;}
    }
    
    .q2{
      width: <?php echo intval(100*round($no/($no+$yes),2));?>px;
      height: 20px;
      background-color: red; 
      animation-name: second;
      animation-duration: 1s;
      animation-delay: 0s;
      -webkit-animation-name: second;
      -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
      -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
    }

    @keyframes second {
      0% {width: 0px;}
      100% {width: <?php echo(100*round($no/($no+$yes),2));?>;}
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes second {
      0% {width: 0px;}
      100% {width: <?php echo(100*round($no/($no+$yes),2));?>;}
    }
 </style>
</head>

<body>
<h2>Result:</h2>
<table>
<tr>
<td>Yes:</td>
<td>
<div class="q1">
<?php echo(100*round($yes/($no+$yes),2)); ?>%
</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>No:</td>
<td>
<div class="q2">
<?php echo(100*round($no/($no+$yes),2)); ?>%
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<body>
</html>
```